# Cannot Add cordova plugin from github

Tags: cordova, github, plugins, bluetooth

I Have problem with adding plugin from github.

cordova plugin add https://github.com/marcelo-michels/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer.git

**Result :**

```
D:\Cordova\pos>cordova plugin add https://github.com/marcelo-michels/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer.git
Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/marcelo-michels/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer.git via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
CordovaError: Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/marcelo-michels/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\willi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-16T03_44_04_148Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score -1):

Set Npm PROXY before using cordova plugin add use these commands:

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@host:port
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@host:port
```